# How to unit test a derived DataGridViewCell without accessors?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, datagridview, mstest, accessor

I'm writing unit tests (in VS2010) for a DataGridViewCell class that looks a bit like this:

```
    public class MyCell : DataGridViewCell
    {
        protected override object GetFormattedValue(object value, int rowIndex, ref System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellStyle cellStyle, System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter valueTypeConverter, System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter formattedValueTypeConverter, System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewDataErrorContexts context)
        {
            return MyCustomFormatting(value);
        }

        private object MyCustomFormatting(object value)
        {
            var formattedValue = string.Empty;
            // ... logic to test here
            return FormattedValue;
        }
    }
```

I want to test the public property .FormattedValue is set correctly. However this always returns null if the cell being tested has no DataGridView set (I checked this with Telerik's [JustDecompile](http://www.telerik.com/products/decompiler.aspx) refection tool).

I can obviously bypass this and just use accessors to access the protected or private methods, but accessors are deprecated in VS2012 onwards.

How can I unit test this logic without using accessors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since obviously there is a lot to be done to set up the `DataGridViewCell`'s and `DataGridView`'s, why don't you try something else?

First, create a component that does your special formatting:

```
public class SpecialFormatter
{
  public object Format(object value)
  {
    var formattedValue = string.Empty;
    // ... logic to test here
    return FormattedValue;
  }
}
```

And then use it your `DataGridViewCell` implementation:

```
public class MyCell : DataGridViewCell
{
  protected override object GetFormattedValue(object value, int rowIndex, ref System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellStyle cellStyle, System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter valueTypeConverter, System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter formattedValueTypeConverter, System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewDataErrorContexts context)
  {
    return MyCustomFormatting(value);
  }

  private object MyCustomFormatting(object value)
  {
    return new SpecialFormatter.Format(value);
  }
}
```

Then you go ahead and unit test `SpecialFormatter` and you're done. Unless there is much else going on in your `DataGridViewCell` implementation, then there is not much value in testing it.

Answer (score 0):

I did find this info on MSDN [Upgrading Unit Tests from Visual Studio 2010](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh507838.aspx) where it explains about using [PrivateObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.privateobject.aspx) if melike's answer is not an option for some reason.

Even though melike's answer worked for me, I thought I'd just learn how this works, here's a sample test in case it helps anyone:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void MyCellExampleTest()
    {
        var target = new MyCell();
        var targetPrivateObject = new PrivateObject(target);

        var result = targetPrivateObject.Invoke("MyCustomFormatting", new object[] { "Test" });

        Assert.AreEqual(string.Empty, result);
    }
```

One obvious downside of using the PrivateObject is the method name is just stored as a string - will be harder to maintain if you change the name or method signature.